# sql query with in clause in oledb source ssis

Tags: t-sql, ssis

Hope everyone is doing well. I am new in ssis and I am badly stuck.

I have a ssis package which has a Oracle oledb source and sql server oledb destination. The oracle oledb source has a parameterized sql query .

I have a string variable *@resultset* with a list of comma seperated id's which I have parsed from an execute sql task object variable. *value of @resultset is like this 111,2222,333,444*

I need to feed this string variable to the in clause in the parameterized source query.

I am using sql command from variable in the oledb source. I have stored the query as expression in a variable called *@setquery.*

The query is like this:

*"select col1, col2, ...coln from oracledb.table
where colid in (" + @resultset + ")"*

But I get an error when I try to see the columns."Unable to retrieve column information from data source"

I read that I can use dynamic sql and I tried it but I am not being able to do it right.

I am using sql server 2017 and visual studios for ssdt 2017.

Could you please help!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to set the OLEDB Setting : AlwaysUseDefaulCodePage to True!
Good luck

Comment: Hi ,
I've used Two varaiables sqlstr and params
 and use this expression @[User::sqlstr] + " where id in ("+ @[User::params]+")"  , and it works !

Comment: Hi @abdelilah..thanks for your suggestion. Since my source query is in ORacle I am getting an error than not more than 1000 literals are allowed in in clause. So I will have to use a select statement probably inside the in clause. And I am stuck again as the data I was putting in the in clause of the oracle query is coming from sql server.

Comment: I have posted a new question as I think i need to start from scratch. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58627479/12278561

Comment: I have the same problem, with 85,000 ID's in the ```in``` statement.  I'm going to use SQL to create batches of 1000 ID's at a time, and iterate through using a FOR EACH LOOP CONTAINER